# is there a notification on find my macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, find-my-iphone

when you use find my iphone to locate a macbook does it notify the macbook that you are online?  If I sign into Find My Iphone on my phone and my macbook is in use by someone else, will they see that I have signed in?

Answer (score 3):

Tested empirically...
No, not until I "Played a sound", which played & put up a dialog on the Mac, then I was sent an email, within 2 seconds, which of course arrived on both my iPhone & Mac simultaneously, telling me I'd 'Played a sound'.

So, you can check the location without any notification, provided that's all you do.